# django_python3_ldap using multiple OU in LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE

Tags: django, ldap

need some help...

i'm using django_python3_ldap and it works fine when i change settings.py for each run using different LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE .

```
userxxx is logged in with LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASEOU=Users,OU=xxx Accounts,OU=ZZZ,DC=domain,DC=local
useryyy is logged in with LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASEOU=Users,OU=yyy Accounts,OU=ZZZ,DC=domain,DC=local
```

i have tried with

```
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASEOU=OU=Users,OU=xxx Accounts,OU=yyy Accounts,OU=ZZZ,DC=domain,DC=local
```

and this gives
noSuchObjec ..... 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100241, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT),

any hint?

Comment: You need to set the search base to a common ancestor in the node tree : 'xxx Accounts' and 'yyy Accounts' OUs are both under 'OU=ZZZ', so `LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "OU=ZZZ,DC=domain,DC=local"` should be fine.

Comment: Sorry no. neither OU=zzz nor OU=users alone worked. Same error as the one where all were added. 
But the one user useryyy has no MemberOf - it is empty. could that give any problem?
the names i found and added to search base was from the DistinguishedName. so i maybe it its there the problem is.
but i'm a bit confused because then, the usersyyy work on many other tools?

Comment: `LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "OU=ZZZ,DC=domain,DC=local"`.

Comment: It was What i testet. I shortned the text in here..

Comment: You say it works fine for userxxx with `OU=Users,OU=xxx Accounts,OU=ZZZ,DC=domain,DC=local`, so it should work the same with a larger base (the top nodes don't change, ie. read right to left to go down the tree). Same for useryyy. Except if you changed another settings in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution using backends.py, and by using this i did not need any package.
Thanks for some of the guidance